# How to implement Swift's or Objective-C's mutable pointers in Python?

Tags: python, pointers

The following function requires a "mutable pointer". How do I represent that in Python?

Swift:

```
func CGPDFDocumentGetVersion(
  _ document: CGPDFDocument?,
  _ majorVersion: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>,
  _ minorVersion: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>
)
```

Objective-C:

```
void CGPDFDocumentGetVersion (
  CGPDFDocumentRef document,
  int *majorVersion,
  int *minorVersion
);
```

Seems a bit mad that the function returns values in this way, nonetheless.

I've tried just supplying variables, already assigned to empty values, but I get a segmentation fault. If the variables are undefined, I get:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Here's some code that causes a Sgmentation fault. It's very easy to get these if CoreGraphics doesn't like the input.

```
file = "/path/to/file.pdf"
pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(file))
x = None
y = None
version = CGPDFDocumentGetVersion(pdf, x, y)
```

Comment: can you provide your code in python?

Comment: How are you getting a _segmentation fault_ from Python code?  Please [edit] your question to provide us a [mcve].

Comment: You're assigning `None` to `pdf_doc` (the output of `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider`... whatever that is).  But this is far from what your question originally asked.  You were originally trying to translate an Objective-C construct --- mutable pointers --- into Python.  Now (it looks like) you're trying to work with some Python package that already exists.  So either [edit] your question so that there is a single, coherent, specific question --- with enough relevant code provided so we can figure out what you're doing --- or ask your new question as... well, a new question.

Comment: The package is OS X CoreGraphics. Are you saying the last line of the code gives pdf_doc the value None? All I'm trying to do is get the version number of a PDF document, using the method described in ObjC and Swift above. But the pointers flummoxed me.

Comment: Please don't replace answered questions with another, different question. Please post a *new* question post instead.

Comment: "So edit your question so that there is a single, coherent, specific question --- with enough relevant code provided so we can figure out what you're doing"
Sorry. Still learning all the rules. Instead of learning python.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need mutable pointers at all.  There are two common uses for pointers to `int` (or similar storage) in C-like code, and Python provides better ways to do both.

### Case 1:  Multiple return values

A C-like function can't return more than one value without defining a new `struct` and allocating memory for it.  That's tedious enough the job is often foisted off onto the calling function, which provides pointers to the storage *it* has allocated in advance.

In Python, you'd just return an object... in your case, a `tuple` or [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
import collections

Version = collections.namedtuple(
  'Version',
  ('major', 'minor'),
  )

class PDFDocument:

    def __init__(self, ...):
        # Figure out major and minor version numbers, then...
        self.version = Version(major, minor)

pdf_doc = PDFDocument(...)
major, minor = pdf_doc.version
...
```

### Case 2: Announcing Errors

A C-like function that needs to signal that an error has occurred will typically return some "illegal" value.  If there *is* no such value it can use, an alternative is to take a pointer to some storage the caller owns, where it will scribble its exit status on its way out.

In Python, you'd just `raise` an exception, which is better in almost every way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not sure what replaces the dots after "self," though. I'll add my code to the question, because formatting in Comments is rubbish.

Comment: @benwiggy:  The ellipses represent whatever you think would create a useful `PDFDocument` class.

Comment: @Kevin-J-Chase I have no idea what that might be. I've tried a number of things: object attributes, assigned variables, CoreGraphics object names, and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: I still don't understand how the PDF class is supposed to work in relation to the original code.